# Is not SH + not CH consistent?

Tags: set-theory, trees

I guess that $\lnot$SH + $\lnot$CH is consistent, but I have not found this question discussed anywhere. Is there any relatively simple model of $\lnot$SH + $\lnot$CH?

Comment: HS or SH? And what exactly do you mean by that? Suslin Hypothesis? In that case, taking from Wikipedia's enty on **Suslin's problem**: "*The Suslin hypothesis is independent of ZFC, and is independent of both the generalized continuum hypothesis (proved by Ronald Jensen[3]) and of the negation of the continuum hypothesis.*"

Comment: Sorry, it was SH. I am aware that Jensen obtained a model for GCH + SH. I suppose that Wikipedia refers to this fact. I have studied a modern proof of this result (a variant of Shelah's one) based on a countable support iteration of proper forcing posets, but I do not know any model of $\lnot$SH + $\lnot$CH. The Souslin trees are usually constructed with $\Diamond$, which implies CH.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Recall that adding a single Cohen real adds a Suslin tree, and does not change the value of the continuum [1] [2]. So by taking any model of $\lnot\sf CH$ and adding a single Cohen real, we have a Suslin tree, and therefore $\lnot\sf SH$ as well.

(This makes the Solovay-Tennenbaum theorem all the more magical, since we add so many Suslin trees in the iteration, but we still manage to kill them all eventually...)

---

1. Jech, **Set Theory, 3rd Millennium ed.**, Theorem 28.12, p.563
2. *Saharon Shelah*, [**Can you take Solovay’s inaccessible away?**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF02760522), *Israel J. Math.* **48** (1984), no. 1, 1--47.

Answer (score 11):

Two more solutions.

1. Start with a model with a Suslin tree $(T,\leq)$ in it 
   (force it or use L). Let $(P,\leq)$ be the Cohen forcing adding 
   any number of reals. We claim that $(T,\leq)$ remains Suslin after 
   forcing with $(P,\leq)$. Assume that $p$ forces that $A$ is an 
   uncountable antichain in $T$. There are conditions $p_\alpha\leq p$ 
   and distinct elements $t_\alpha\in T$ such that $p_\alpha$ forces 
   that $t_\alpha\in A$. An easy argument (using the delta system lemma) 
   shows that there is an uncountable set $Z$ such that 
   any finite subfamily of $\{p_\alpha:\alpha\in Z\}$ has a common lower bound. 
   Then $\{t_\alpha:\alpha\in Z\}$ is an antichain, as if $\alpha\neq\beta$ are 
   in $Z$, then some $p'\leq p_\alpha,p_\beta$ forces that $t_\alpha$, 
   $t_\beta$ are both in $A$. Contradiction to the fact that $T$ is Suslin 
   in the ground model.
2. In Jech's above mentioned book, there is a forcing adding a Suslin tree 
   with finite conditions (in the exercises). Force with it over a model 
   of non-CH.

In K. Devlin: $\aleph_1$ trees, Annals of Math. Logic, 13(1978), 267-330, all combinations of CH, ST (there exists a Suslin tree) and KT (there exists a Kurepa tree) and their negations are considered.